# Sequelize same N:M table for different associations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sequelize.js

In a Node + MySQL project I got 4 Tables:

- `Users` describes a registered user,
- `InvitedUsers` a proto-user, contains some informations of a non registered user,
- `Projects` describes a project,
- `ProjectMembers` the N:M associations of `Projects` and `Users`

Now I got the association of the N:M like this:

```
Users.belongsToMany(Projects, { through: ProjectMembers });
Projects.belongsToMany(Users, { through: ProjectMembers });
```

**I need to use the same `ProjectMembers` table as N:M for `InvitedUsers` and `Projects`**

**Is this possible?** I suppose that it's not since the foreign key constrains on the N:M table cannot choose on which table (`Users` or `InvitedUsers`) has to be applied

I've tried adding (omitting the options):

```
InvitedUsers.belongsToMany(Projects, { through: ProjectMembers });
Projects.belongsToMany(InvitedUsers, { through: ProjectMembers });
```

And no error is displayed during the associations definition but when i try to add an entry in the `ProjectMembers` table coping a `InvitedUsers`'s id as FK, I got a foreign key constrain error.

So my question is if I can use a N:M table for different N:M relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this can be done as long as you specify which `foreignKey` the association should use for joining the tables. You can specify two different keys, one for `user` and one for the `InvitedUser` and Sequelize will pick the right key.

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'project_id' });
Invited.belongsToMany(Project, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'invited_id' });
Project.belongsToMany(Invited, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'project_id' });
```

This is how the schema of `project_members` would look like

[image: Schema for n:m relation]

Below is the full working code

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Invited = sequelize.define('invited', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const ProjectMembers = sequelize.define('project_members', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
  project_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  invited_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
});

User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'project_id' });
Invited.belongsToMany(Project, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'invited_id' });
Project.belongsToMany(Invited, { through: ProjectMembers, foreignKey: 'project_id' });

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    User.create({
      username: 'UserOne',
      projects: {
        projectName: 'projectOne'
      }
    }, { include: [Project] }).then((result) => {
      Invited.create({
        username: 'InvitedOne',
        projects: {
          projectName: 'projectTwo'
        }
      }, { include: [Project] }).then((result2) => {
        console.log(result2);

      })
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

Speaking from MySQL's perspective...

A many:many *database* table is essentially 2 columns (`project_id`, `person_id`) with two indexes (`(project_id, person_id)` and `(person_id, project_id)`).  If is reasonable to add a 3rd column to qualify the type of relationship between the ("member" versus "invited user").

More discussion of the table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating different alias using `as` option in `belongsToMany`
So, your associations might look like this -

```
//User-projects via ProjectMembers
Users.belongsToMany(Projects, { through: ProjectMembers, as: 'ProjectMembers' });
Projects.belongsToMany(Users, { through: ProjectMembers, as: 'ProjectMembers' });

//InvitedUsers-Projects via ProjectMembers
InvitedUsers.belongsToMany(Projects, { through: ProjectMembers, as: 'ProjectInvitedMembers' });
Projects.belongsToMany(InvitedUsers, { through: ProjectMembers, as: 'ProjectInvitedMembers' });
```